# typescript Nullish coalescing

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why typescript gives me a WARNING for a code like the below-mentioned one. the generated code works as expected, but `typescript` complains that `key1` doesn't exist on one of the objects. I mean that's true whereas that's what the `??`
Is there some ways I can write it differently?

```js
const foobar = {
    foo: { key1: 2 },
    bar: { key2: 2 }
}


function getValue(someKey: keyof typeof foobar){
    return foobar[someKey].key1 ?? 0
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAjAhgJxgXhgbwFAyHyIBcuMA1gKYCeAjGQEwwC%20ANAUammTpbYyas8LPGLgBXMMCgBLcDADmVKADUUAGwlUAFBBABbKgGlaZajRBwYUGgAcqV4snQBKfERhoVEtGGfcANr6RqY0ALoAdBZ0MAD8cTAADCJieEA)

Comment: `keyof typeof foobar` = `"foo" | "bar"`, but `foobar['bar']` object doesn't have key `key1`

Comment: Yes, but the case oh 'object doesn't have key `key1`' is propery handled by nullish coalescing, there should not be a warning here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nullish coalescing in your example happens **after** the type error. You're trying to use `key1` on a type that may or may not have it. `foobar[someKey]` has the type `{ key1: number; } | { key2: number; }`. Since `someKey` may be `"bar"`, `key1` may not exist. You need a guard to differentiate between the type with `key1` and the type with `key2` before you can use either of those in the function. (And then there's no need for nullish coalescing, since you know that `key1` isn't `null` or `undefined`.)

For instance:

```
function getValue(someKey: keyof typeof foobar){
    const obj = foobar[someKey];
    return "key1" in obj ? obj.key1 : 0;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAjAhgJxgXhgbwFAyHyIBcuMA1gKYCeAjGQEwwC+ANAUammTpbYyas8LPGLgBXMMCgBLcDADmVKADUUAGwlUAFBBABbKgGlaZajRBwYUGgAcqV4snQBKfERihIsZACssZ24AbX0jUxoAXQBuTkI0FQk0MBgAIgs6VJhZFP8YAH4YfwA6DJgyAAZYliA)

Or to avoid the `in` operation (I'm sometimes guilty of premature micro-optimization):

```
function getValue(someKey: keyof typeof foobar){
    return someKey === "foo" ? foobar.foo.key1 : 0;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAjAhgJxgXhgbwFAyHyIBcuMA1gKYCeAjGQEwwC+ANAUammTpbYyas8LPGLgBXMMCgBLcDADmVKADUUAGwlUAFBBABbKgGlaZajRBwYUGgAcqV4snQBKfERhoVEtGBj6RqY0WJjYAEQIIOEwAPzO3AB0UYkWdDBkAAwA3CJAA)

Remember that telling you when you try to use a property on an object when that object's type doesn't define a property with that name is one of TypeScript's primary jobs. That's what it's doing with the error on your original code.

Comment: Yes, but the nullish coalescing handles the case of 'key1' missing. If `key1` had no possibililties of missing, the nulish operator would be useless. It probably is an edge case not properly managed by typescript

Comment: @gbalduzzi - I literally **just** edited the answer one second before your comment, having figured out why you were calling out the nullish coalescing. :-) Please see the update, I think it'll answer your query above. It's handled perfectly well. You're thinking runtime values, but TypeScript's job is to enforce a *type* system. It's doing its primary job here: Warning you when you try to use a property that doesn't exist on a type.

Comment: Yeah, I see why typescript does that and it kinda makes sense. But at the same time it is clear for a human that the code is perfecty working and should not rise any warning

Comment: If you wanted to use nullish concealing, you just have to cast `someKey` to `foo`, typescript complains because even without the `??` `key1` does not exist on every key of `foobar`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I dont think nullish concealing is nescessary here either, but is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAjAhgJxgXhgbwFAyHyIBcuMA1gKYCeAjGQEwwC+ANAUammTpbYyas8LPHjgBXMMCgBLcDADmVKADUUAGwlUAFBBABbKgGlaZajRBwYUGgAcqV4snQBKfERhoVEtGGfcANr6RqY0MCgQMADkCCDRALoAdBZ0MAD86TAADCJieEA) not doing the same as your function? Where would I typo for it to not work?

Comment: @MikeS. - I misread your comment, sorry about that. That's an interesting solution. :-) I suggest posting it as an answer. It's clever. I can't say I *like* it, but... I'd feel the need for a comment over it saying what I was doing. (I've also suggested an alternative in the answer above avoiding the in operation.)

Comment: the example is just a stripped down one the object has a lot of properties and on some the key is missing. is yes i should probably test it with some Object.hasOwnProperty check or an in. that just doesn't look so nice to me i was not aware that the ?? was only a runtime thing.

Comment: @L.A It is not, consider [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyA7nADYURgD8AXPsgLY4QCejIArswEbRkAXwDcREiDjMIjDGCigA5mJLJgAEy68BUMUIIEEOOcgAOmHI3RRsuALz5xxSdMYAidJDcAaJ2s3IAIwE+gZGICasIBxa-IIO5jY4AHTkVDS0yVEcyLS0yAAMIkA) appropiate usage of the null concealing operator, if you take away the `??` the type of `money` will become `number | undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, as I said the `??` would be very misused in this situation, I was just trying to give an example on how it could still be used.

Comment: @MikeS. - Yeah, that was bad phrasing on my part (the nullish coalescing being a runtime thing). I've fixed it. Like many runtime constructs, it influences the type system.